# Unable to Copy s3 files inside Docker container

Tags: docker, amazon-s3

Am new to docker and aws. I am trying to create a Jmeter Image and pass on the JMX script during runtime. For that, i thought copying files from S3 inside a container will be a best fit. So initially i tried to copy the files from s3 to my local host using the below command

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/sample.jmx .
```

I was able to download the file successfully into my local system.
After then i have created a docker images with latest AWS CLI installed and tried the same, the message shows "download: s3://bucketname/sample.jmx to current folder " but am not able to see the file.
But on the other hand, i was able to copy the file from docker to S3 using the command

```
aws s3 cp /tmp/sample.jmx s3://bucketname/
```

Further details :

1. Image on - alpine:3.12.4
2. Credentials - Passed inline with the docker run command like below

   docker run -it --rm -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-east-2' -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='aaaaaa' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='dsfssdfds' dockerimage  aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/sample.jmx /tmp

Complete Docker file :

```
FROM alpine:3.12.4

ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.3"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL  https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz

# Install extra packages
# Set TimeZone, See: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/136#issuecomment-612751142
ARG TZ="Europe/Amsterdam"
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN    apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
    && apk add --no-cache nss \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
    && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
    && mkdir -p /opt  \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
    && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

# TODO: plugins (later)
# && unzip -oq "/tmp/dependencies/JMeterPlugins-*.zip" -d $JMETER_HOME

# Set global PATH such that "jmeter" command is found
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip\
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/bin/aws
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I would really need some help here.

Comment: Can you download the script to your host system, then use a `docker run -v` bind mount to inject it into the container?  That will probably be easier (and safer) than trying to push valid AWS credentials in.  If the script is relatively stable, `COPY`ing it into the image is also a good choice.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for reverting back. I was trying to run the docker container as Fargate service, that was the reason I was trying go with this option.

Comment: Found the issue and I was able to copy it, it was because of permission issue inside container.